# cfdisk or fdisk?

Tags: linux, command-line, fdisk, cfdisk

While reading the man page for `fdisk` I came across this interesting text:

> There are several *fdisk programs around.  Each has its problems and strengths.   Try  them  in  the  order
>          cfdisk,  fdisk,  sfdisk.  (Indeed, cfdisk is a beautiful program that has strict requirements on the parti‐
>          tion tables it accepts, and produces high quality partition tables.  Use it if you can.  fdisk is  a  buggy
>          program that does fuzzy things - usually it happens to produce reasonable results.  Its single advantage is
>          that it has some support for BSD disk labels and other non-DOS partition tables.   Avoid  it  if  you  can.
>          sfdisk  is  for  hackers only -- the user interface is terrible, but it is more correct than fdisk and more
>          powerful than both fdisk and cfdisk.  Moreover, it can be used noninteractively.)

I notice that the option formats are not the same for the two applications:

```
 - melancholy():/$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00036f1b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    39063551    19530752   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        39063552   976771071   468853760   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00085251

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048    15624191     7811072   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdc2   *    15624192    64452607    24414208   83  Linux
/dev/sdc3        64454654  1953523711   944534529    5  Extended
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sdc5        64454656  1953523711   944534528   83  Linux
 - melancholy():/$ sudo cfdisk -l
cfdisk: invalid option -- 'l'

Usage:
Print version:
        cfdisk -v
Print partition table:
        cfdisk -P {r|s|t} [options] device
Interactive use:
        cfdisk [options] device

Options:
-a: Use arrow instead of highlighting;
-z: Start with a zero partition table, instead of reading the pt from disk;
-c C -h H -s S: Override the kernel's idea of the number of cylinders,
                the number of heads and the number of sectors/track.

Copyright (C) 1994-2002 Kevin E. Martin & aeb
```

**Is there real merit in switching to using `cfdisk` instead of `fdisk`, or is the man page note a historical observation that is no longer valid?** Since `fdisk` works fine for listing the disks info (`-l` flag) should I use `cfdisk` only for altering the partitions and partition tables? **What are the real strengths and weaknesses of each application?**

Comment: For modern hard disks, >2TB, `fdisk` is useless: it doesn't support GPT partition tables.

Comment: @John1024: I'm glad I asked, I just installed a 2TiB disk but have not formatted it yet (sdb in the OP). Do you mean `>=2 TiB` or just `>2 TiB`? In other words, should I expect fdisk to work with sdb (2 TiB) that I just installed? Thanks!

Comment: I believe that the failure is only for `>2 TiB`.  For such large disks, `fdisk` will partition only the first 2 TiB and leave the rest unused.  From `fdisk`, run the `v` command to "verify" and it will inform you if you have unused space.

Comment: @John1024 - latest versions (partially) [do](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/commit/?id=766d5156c43b784700d28d1c1141008b2bf35ed7) support gpt...

Comment: @don_crissti Good link.  Thanks.  I appreciated the honesty in the author's test report but it did leave me less than confident::  "For the image, all operations were tested successfully, and for /dev/sda all except write, which was not tested - hey, I'm not suicidal!"

Comment: neither - use `gdisk` - it is the best of them.

Comment: +1 for `gdisk`. Both `fdisk` and `cfdisk` support GPT now, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`cfdisk` is a graphical application designed to be more friendly to the novice.  If you are comfortable with `fdisk`, then by all means, use it.  If you prefer a bit more hand holding and fewer ( advanced ) options, use `cfdisk`.  Another good alternative is GNU `parted`.